# new session opencart checkout

Tags: php, opencart, shopping-cart

I want to add a new `session['abc']` during the checkout *Step 5: Payment Method* (1.5.5.1).

What I've done so far:

`/template/checkout/payment_method.tpl` add

```
<input type="hidden" name="abc" value="1111"  id="abc">
```

`/template/checkout/checkout.tpl`

```
data: $('#payment-method input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #payment-method input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #payment-method textarea'),
```

changed to

```
data: $('#payment-method input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #payment-method input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #payment-method textarea, #payment-method input[type=\'hidden\']'),
```

`/controller/checkou/payment_method.php` after

```
$this->session->data['payment_method'] = $this->session->data['payment_methods'][$this->request->post['payment_method']];
```

added

```
$this->session->data['abc'] = strip_tags($this->request->post['abc']);
```

and the error message is

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

OK

<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index:  salutation in <b>D:\phpnow\PHPnow-1.5.6\htdocs\1\catalog\controller\checkout\payment_method.php</b> on line <b>190</b>[]
```

Comment: What is in line 190 in payment_method.php file? And try console.log($('#payment-method input[type=\'hidden\']).val()) after $('#button-payment-method').live('click', function() { line to see what data being submitted

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to **StackOverflow**.

In Your controller's code (`/controller/checkou/payment_method.php`) You probably have somewhere this kind of code:

```
echo 'OK';
```

or

```
print('OK');
```

or

```
die('OK');
```

That comes prior the JSON output. In addition, the index `salutation` in some array is not defined (does not exist) thus You should first test for it's presence e.g. this way:

```
if(isset($some_array['salutation'])) { /* Your code then */ }
```

or

```
if(!empty($some_array['salutation'])) { /* Your code then */ }
```

Removing the `echo 'OK';` and testing for the array index should fix the problem.